# Perl : function call in constructor?

Tags: perl, class, constructor

I would like to ameliorate my perl script which does SNMP request on a cisco switch. But I don't really understand constructor and giving args to function in perl...
This is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SNMP;
package SnmpTable;

my ($session, $error);

sub new {
  my ($classe, $hostname, $oid, $community) = @_;
  my $this = {
    "hostname"      => $hostname,
    "oid"           => $oid,
    "community" => $community
  };
  bless($this, $classe);
  return $this;
}

sub connexion {
    my ($this) = @_;
    #print "Connexion SNMP...\n";
    ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
        -hostname  => $this->{hostname},
        -community => $this->{community},
        -version   => "1",
        -timeout   => 3,
    );
    request_error_connexion() if (!defined($session));
    #print "Connexion établie\n";
}

sub request_error_connexion {   
    my ($this) = @_;
    print "Erreur : connexion SNMP impossible vers $this->{hostname}\n";
    print "Erreur : $error\n";
    if ($error =~ /The argument "-community" is unknown/)
        {
                # protocol SNMP version 3 non pris en charge
                exit 3;  # code retour final = 3*256 = 768
        }
    else
    {
        exit 1; # code retour final = 1*256 = 256
    }
}

sub request_error {
        my ($this) = @_;
        #print "Erreur : pas de réponse SNMP depuis l'hôte $this->{hostname} avec l'oid $this->{oid}\n";
        printf "Erreur : %s\n",$session->error;
        if ($session->error =~ /No response from remote host/)
        {
                #host ok, mais community surement erronée ou host refuse le connexion
                $session->close;
                exit 2; # code retour final = 2*256 = 512
        }
        else
        {
                #table introuvable
                $session->close;
                exit 4; # code retour final = 4*256 = 1024
        }
}

sub requete {
    my ($this) = @_;
    my $result = $session->get_table( -baseoid => $this->{oid} );
    request_error() if (!defined($result));
    my %tab = ();

    foreach my $i (Net::SNMP::oid_lex_sort(keys %{$result})) {
        my $index = $i;
        $index =~ s/$this->{oid}.//;
        $tab{ $index } = $result->{$i};  
        #print $index."--".$result->{$i}."\n";
    }

    $session->close();
    return %tab;
}

1;
```

In my constructor, I would like to create the SNMP session (using Net::SNMP), and not have to do it in a function 'connexion()'. When I create the instance, connexion() called automatically.
Moreover, I want function 'requete()' with arg (OID).
So I could create only one instance, and doing all my request with it.
With that script I must create instances as many informations I want.

Hope, it's comprehensible...
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `new`, before `return` put this:

```
$this->connexion;
```

To the OID parameter part:

```
sub requete {
    my ($this, $oid) = @_;

    $oid = $this->{oid}
        unless defined $oid;

    my $result = $session->get_table( -baseoid => $oid );
    request_error() if (!defined($result));
    my %tab = ();

    foreach my $i (Net::SNMP::oid_lex_sort(keys %{$result})) {
        my $index = $i;
        $index =~ s/$this->{oid}.//;
        $tab{ $index } = $result->{$i};  
        #print $index."--".$result->{$i}."\n";
    }

    $session->close();
    return %tab;
}
```

This will accept OID as a parameter, it the OID is not given as a parameter it will use OID from constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but here's a go at trying to answer:

1. How do subroutine arguments work in Perl?
2. How does a constructor work in Perl?

Answers:

### How do subroutine arguments work?

Subroutines in Perl are a bit unusual.  See perldoc perlsub for all the details.

The short version is that any call to a subroutine is passed a **list of arguments**.  It is up to the called code to handle the list however it wants.

The argument list is stored in the special `@_` array.  The members of `@_` are actually aliases of the values passed in (think in terms of pass by reference), so it is possible to modify a calling argument.  To avoid any accidents, most subroutines copy the elements of `@_` into local variables.  When you see `my ($foo, $bar) = @_;`, it copies the first two members of `@_` into `$foo` and `$bar`.  Another common idiom is `my $foo = shift;`.  This removes the first item from `@_` and copies it into `$foo`.

### How does a constructor work?

In Perl OO methods are just subroutines, and the constructor is no different.

When you call a method `$foo->do_this()` or `MyCoolClass->new()` the item on the left side of the `->` operator is called the *invocant*.  The invocant determines in what name-spaces (packages in perl terms) the method will be searched for.  When the invocant is a string literal, it is taken to be name of the package or class to start the search in.  When the invocant is a scalar, it must be an object.  In either case the invocant is also passed in as the first argument to the method when it is found and called.  So a class method (such as `new()`) will expect a string for its first argument, while an instance method will expect an object.

A constructor, typically `new()` is usually a class method that creates an instance of the class to which it belongs.  So `Foo->new()` will create a new `Foo` object.

A perl object is any reference that has been associated with a package by the use of the bless function.

Let's look at your constructor and see how it works:

```
sub new {

  # Unpack @_ into local variables
  # Notice that the class name is the first argument.
  my ($classe, $hostname, $oid, $community) = @_;


  # Create a reference to a hash with the arguments associated 
  # to particular keys in the hash.
  my $this = {
    "hostname"      => $hostname,
    "oid"           => $oid,
    "community" => $community
  };

  # Associate the hash ref with the class
  bless($this, $classe);

  # $this is now an object.  You can make method calls on it here.


  return $this;
}
```

Since constructor is like any other method or subroutine in Perl, you can do anything you want to in it.  It's generally considered a good idea to keep your subroutines as simple as possible, but there is no reason why you couldn't make a Net::SNMP object in your constructor.  If you make one, you should probably store it for later use.

```
sub new {
  my ($classe, $hostname, $oid, $community) = @_;

  my $this = {
    "hostname"      => $hostname,
    "oid"           => $oid,
    "community"     => $community,
    "connexion"     => undef,
  };

  bless($this, $classe);

  # Store the connection for later.
  # You could also modify connexion so that it stores the connection for you.
  $this->{connexion} = $this->connexion;

  return $this;
}
```

All this code presupposes that we want to use classical Perl OOP methods.  While these techniques work well, there is a huge amount of activity surrounding the Moose Perl OO framework.  Moose simplifies writing solid, well encapsulated OO code in Perl.

I strongly suggest that you pick up a copy of a book like [Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/).  It will give you an updated look at Perl's OO tools, an introduction to Moose, as well as demonstrate many simple techniques that will make your code much easier to maintain.

I hope this is useful.